# Android - How to work with complex object via socket

Tags: java, android, json, sockets

I'm kind of new to Android and I have a task to open a TCP socket and listen to a specific port.
A client application is supposed to send me 2 images and a string that are related to each other so instead of sending each data alone we thought about putting all data in a json object and send this object.
My question is, how do I parse this json into saving 2 images and a string?
So this json is supposed to be like this:

```
data
{
    FileName: "some string",
    Image1: "Image encoded with encode base64",
    Image2: "Image encoded with encode base64"
}
```

I'm using an AsyncTask so here is the code where I get the socket data:

```
public class DataRecord
{
    String Image1;
    String Image2;
    String FileName;
}


protected DataRecord doInBackground(Socket... sockets) {
DataRecord dataRecord = null;

if (isExternalStorageWritable() && sockets.length > 0) {
    Socket socket = sockets[0];

    dataRecord = socket.getOutputStream(); // how to extract the data from the socket into this object ???

    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), dataRecord.FileName);

    byte[] bytes = new byte[(int) file.length()];
    BufferedInputStream inputStream;
    try {
        inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
        inputStream.read(bytes, 0, bytes.length);

        OutputStream outputStream = dataRecord.Image1;
        outputStream.write(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
        outputStream.flush();

        socket.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e) { }
    finally {
        try {
            socket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) { }
    }
}
return dataRecord;
}
```

And I need to get it from the socket object and extract an object from it to save the 2 images to the SD card and extract the string to the UI.

Comment: Sorry i do not understand what problems you have. If you can write to a socket thenwhy would reading be a problem?. Looks pretty elementary to me. After that...What problem do you have to extract the values of those three parameters from the json?

Comment: Dont understand why you cannot read from a socket object. The server sends a json text. It's just text. You can read it. Your client just has to read that text from the inputstream.

Comment: But anyhow its a bad idea to use base64 and json to transfer files. The amount of bytes to be transported enlarges with at least 30%.

Comment: You say two images. Do you mean image files?

Comment: @greenapps, Thanks for your comments. I'm new to Android and to Java so I wanted to know how to do the deserialization from json string to an object, with C# I use newtonsoft, I don't know of any way in Java. Regarding the base 64, this is how the client sends is to me, he doesn't know any other way in Python, I would use byte[]. And finally, yes, I mean 2 image ".png" files.

Comment: If you just read fifty stackoverflow pages tagged `android` you would find solutions for -extracting the three strings from json, -convert base64 string to byte array, -saving byte array to file. Every week that code is posted again. Read! Read!

Comment: I'll search and read now. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this question probably have more than one answer, but still posting an answer is a good idea.
So, I found this link here [A Simple Java TCP Server and TCP Client](https://systembash.com/a-simple-java-tcp-server-and-tcp-client/) which helped me getting started with my solution.
I've also used Gson to parse my JSON string using this nice tutorial: [Android JSON Parsing with Gson Tutorial](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/01/android-json-parsing-gson-tutorial.html).
Finally, my code looks like this:

**ServerSockerThread.java** - this is the java class for the listening server which waits for incoming files:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class ServerSocketThread extends Thread {
    static final int SocketServerPORT = 6789;
    ServerSocket serverSocket;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Socket socket = null;
        try {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(SocketServerPORT);
            while (true) {
                socket = serverSocket.accept();
                new FileSaveThread().execute(socket);
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e) { }
        finally {
            if (socket != null) {
                try {
                    socket.close();
                } catch (IOException e) { }
            }
        }
    }

    protected void onDestroy() {
        if (serverSocket != null) {
            try {
                serverSocket.close();
            }
            catch (IOException e) { }
        }
    }
}
```

**FileSaveThread.java** - this is the java class that is being called by the above server class for each incoming file:

```
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Base64;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.net.Socket;

public class FileSaveThread extends AsyncTask<Socket, Void, DataRecord> {

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(DataRecord dataRecord) {
        super.onPostExecute(dataRecord);        
    }

    @Override
    protected DataRecord doInBackground(Socket... sockets) {
        DataRecord dataRecord = null;

        if (isExternalStorageWritable() && sockets.length > 0) {
            Socket socket = sockets[0];
            try {
                Gson gson = new Gson();
                Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream());
                SocketObject socketObject = gson.fromJson(reader, SocketObject.class);              

                SaveFileToSDCard(socketObject.Image1, "Image1.png");
                SaveFileToSDCard(socketObject.Image2, "Image2.png");
                SaveFileToSDCard(socketObject.Image3, "Image3.png");

                dataRecord = new DataRecord(socketObject.Name);
            }
            catch (Exception e) { }
            finally {
                try {
                    socket.close();
                } catch (IOException e) { }
            }
        }
        return dataRecord;
    }

    public boolean isExternalStorageWritable() {
        String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
        if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private void SaveFileToSDCard(String base64String, String fileName) throws IOException {
        byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(base64String.getBytes(), android.util.Base64.DEFAULT);
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), fileName);
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file, false);
        fileOutputStream.write(decodedString);
        fileOutputStream.close();
        fileOutputStream.flush();
    }
}
```